# How to disable the "Save As" tab in Word 2016

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have a VSTO add-in that I developed for Word 2010 and I'm currently in the process of upgrading to Office 2016. One of the things I do is, in the ribbon xml, disable the save as command (<command idMso="FileSaveAs" getEnabled="IsFileSaveAsEnabled" ...>) with certain documents. However, it appears that Microsoft have added a new Save As tab to the backstage view in Word 2016 that I can't dynamically disable.

The disabling of the save as command effects the Save As button if it's added to the quick access toolbar, but it does not effect the tab on the back stage view. I've tried changing other things on this tab and it appears to ignore any changes I attempt to make.

I'm developing in VS 2017 and automatically migrated the project to Office 2016.

If I add

```
<backstage>
    ...
    <tab idMso="TabSave" getEnabled="IsFileSaveEnabled" />
    ...
</backstage>
```

to my ribbon.xml the IsFileSaveEnabled isn't invoked.

```
public bool IsFileSaveEnabled(IRibbonControl control) 
{
    return false; // Not the actual implementation, but you get the idea.
}
```

In fact even setting the enabled attribute to false does nothing, however this

```
<backstage>
    ...
    <tab idMso="TabSave" visible="false" />
    ...
</backstage>
```

does actually hide the tab. Though this is no good because this will happen for all documents, but I want it to be conditional.

So is it just not possible to disable this tab the way I want to or is there something new I need to do? I can't really find anything else on the web about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here as I thought of a work around. Instead of trying to interact with the built in save as tab I'm just going to permanently hide it and add my own copy of this tab that I create from scratch to look and behave exactly like the built in tab. Bit more work, but can't think of any other way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If the visibility should be conditional then the setting needs to be dynamic. That means it requires a *callback* rather than a static setting:

```
<tab idMso="TabSave" getVisible="procedureName" />
```

This procedure needs to be in the Ribbon1.cs (or whatever the class is called in your VSTO project) and the logic for making the control visible (or not) - same as `IsFileSaveEnabled`. The callback will trigger when the Ribbon loads the first time, and any time the control (or entire Ribbon) is invalidated (`Ribbon.Invalidate` / `InvalidateControl(controlID)`). This would usually be done in an event such as DocumentOpen, DocumentClose, DocumentChange, etc.

I'm assuming you already have procedures to initialize a `Ribbon` object in your code (`GetCustomUI` and `Ribbon_Load`).

Here's a simple example I have in a test project, that toggles the visibility of a Group:

```
    private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon; //initialized via Ribbon's load event
    bool bGetVisible = false;

    //triggered by clicking a Ribbon control
    public void ShowFontGroup_Click(Office.IRibbonControl ctl)
    {
        bGetVisible = true;
        ribbon.Invalidate(); //triggers all "get" callbacks in the Ribbon
    }

    //callback triggered by invalidating the Ribbon
    public bool GroupFont_GetVisible(Office.IRibbonControl ctl)
    {
        return bGetVisible;
    }
```

Comment: My problem is the callback isn't invoked for TabSave, even if I do Ribbon.Invalidate. TabSave didn't exist in Office 2010, so must have been new in either 2013 or 2016. In 2010 Save as was just a command in the backstage so disabling the command did what i needed. In 2016 save as is a tab that does not appear to behave the same as other built in tabs. Wondering if anyone knew why and if there is a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Word 2016 so I can't verify this, but you could probably intercept the save event and abort when it's a Save As.

```
// this is for a document-level add-in; do this in your startup method
BeforeSave += new SaveEventHandler(ThisDocument_BeforeSave);

private void ThisDocument_BeforeSave(object sender, SaveEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = e.ShowSaveAsDialog;
    return;
}
```

I do something similar in my add-in and it works well.